# Inputting Multibyte Characters in C

Tags: c, algorithm, macos, char

I'm currently working on a program in C and I need to read a multibyte character from the keyboard. I want to input a two-byte character (e.g., "ą") and ensure that I can't input more than one character. Additionally, I'd like to handle the case where an attempt to input a multibyte character results in an error.

Please, if possible, provide an example of simple code in the C language. ;)

I tried to read input using getchar() and then checked whether the buffer is different from the newline character: getchar() != '\n'. Unfortunately, this doesn't allow me to enter characters like "ą" in the input, possibly because something remains in the buffer.

Comment: Do you want to use a UTF-8 library or are you going to bang together your own? C does not normally understand UTF-8.

Comment: I would like to stay in UTF-8. Is it possible?

Comment: The hack way is to look for non 7-bit ASCII and reject it. The proper way is to use a Unicode library to parse your input properly.

Comment: @tadman I have to change my idle UTF-8. ? I think I don't uderstand it properly :\

Comment: @Pedro no your IDE has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: You are asking for something very unusual. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: To prevent the user from entering multiple bytes or multiple characters into the terminal window, `getchar()` is completely useless.

Comment: https://tonsky.me/blog/unicode/ is a basic overview of Unicode that may explain what is complicated about this. (Which is why you should use a library.) Note that its "everything is UTF-8" is true for networking, but not necessarily locally. For example Windows uses UTF-16 a lot. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/unicode

Comment: @pts im using MacOS

Comment: @pts I am solving a problem where I need to input a specific text and then read a character within that text. Next, I need to display the first and last occurrences of that character in the provided text. The challenge here is that I want to secure the program against inputting more than one character for checking, and a character like 'ą' is two bytes, which causes the standard protection to fail. I highly value the capability to handle multi-byte special characters.

Comment: You could read the input as wide characters. Assuming your locale uses UTF-8, `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` will set the process's current locale to also use UTF-8. Then if nothing has been read from `stdin` yet (so the `stdin` stream is not yet "byte-oriented" or "wide-oriented") `fgetwc(stdin);` will mark the `stdin` stream as "wide-oriented", read a multi-byte character from `stdin` and return a wide character (or `WEOF` on error or end-of-file).

Comment: "I want to secure the program against inputting more than one character" This makes little sense. You should read *lines* of input, parse and validate them.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from the question what you really want, and why it is helpful to prevent the user from entering multiple bytes or multiple characters. So I'm focusing my answer on detecting multibyte characters. You are running your program within the macOS Terminal (or something equivalent on macOS). It uses the UTF-8 encoding (character set), in which ASCII characters (with code 0..127) are single-byte, and everything else is multibyte.

Here is a C program which counts and prints the number of bytes and number of Unicode characters on its standard input, for each line. It works on macOS in the Terminal window. (It also works on most Linux systems, because, just like on macOS, the default encoding is UTF-8. It doesn't work on Windows, because many of the terminal programs on Windows don't use UTF-8.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  unsigned bc = 0, cc = 0, lc = 0;
  int c;
  (void)argc; (void)argv;
  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\n') {
      ++lc;
      printf("bytes=%u characters=%u lines=%u\n", bc, cc, lc);
      bc = cc = 0;
    } else {
      ++bc;
      if ((c & 0xc0) != 0x80) ++cc;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The C function call `c = getchar()` returns 1 byte (not character!) or `EOF`. If it's not `EOF`, then the `c` contains the unsigned byte value, in the range 0 .. 255.

The interesting line for counting multibyte characters is:

```c
if ((c & 0xc0) != 0x80) ++cc;
```

In the [UTF-8 encoding](https://linux.die.net/man/7/utf8), multibyte characters start with a leading byte and continue with 1 or more continuation bytes. The leading byte has the bit pattern 11?????? (`(c & 0xc0) == 0xc0`), the continuation bytes have the bit pattern 10?????? (`(c & 0xc0) == 0x80`).

You can use the code snippets above to detect multibyte characters, and then make your program exit with an error message if encountered. You can also use the code above to detect multiple characters (or multiple bytes), and then make your program exit with an error message if encountered.

If you want to write a smarter program, which works with multibyte characters, then you have two options: 1. treat each character as a byte sequence; 2. convert each input line to a sequence of characters (e.g. an array of `uint32_t`) first, and then run the algorithm on that array.

Comment: Why does the "ą" character return 3 bytes? I thought it has 2 bytes.

Comment: On macOS, "ą" may be 2 characters: "a" (ASCII, 1 byte) + a Unicode combining accent (2 bytes). You may want to print each byte (`printf('0x%02x", c & 0xff);`) to verify this. For me, on Linux, "ą" is 1 character, 2 bytes.

Comment: I've modified the program above a bit, the make it always ignore the newlines when counting. You may want to recompile and rerun it.

Comment: @Pedro how do you type ą?